# Pass usercode and returns username with filled field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, linqpad

I am facing some unusual issue on return username..
I am giving brief view,

I am working on web app portal..
I am providing login page..
In login page.. user should enter his login code.. then he get automatically username field fill..just need to enter password and if everything well..he is on dashboard..
I am using entity framework code first approach.. i am facing issue in linq query..
How to validate usercode and return username in filled field and again pass password and validate

Comment: Please [edit] the question and provide relevant code (C# and .cshtml) showing what you tried, or else we won't be able to help.

Comment: Please ***[EDIT]*** the question. You are now creating a mess, with the risk of it being closed without receiving an answer. Also, the "Answer" that you posted below is not an answer - you should *never* post clarifications or additions as "Answers".

Answer (score 0):

You should not put the variable USERCODE in quotes because it will be treated as a string that contains the value "USERCODE".

```
public ActionResult GETUSERNAME(string USERCODE)
    {
        Dbconnects con = new Dbconnects();


        // LoggedUserName
        try
        {
            var user = con.webusers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.w_usr_code == USERCODE);
            if (user != null)
            {

            }
```